# How to install a chaincode with a private npm dependency (private repository)

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

On Hyperledger Fabric we now have the ability to install a chaincode using node js and a `package.json` file describing the code to be run in a script.

As expected with `package.json`, dependencies are resolved and the package runs.

But, is it possible, and if so, how to instantiate a chaincode with a private dependency in the package.json?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, one can copy the `.npmrc` into the docker container to be able to install the private packages.